# Trying to run cmd commands through Java...only first half is runs

Tags: java, postgresql

I am running the below query through Java on a Postgres DB using psql:

```
psql.exe -U <user> -w -h <host> -d <db_name> -a -f <file> 2> "<path_to_file>\psql.log"
```

Initially, for quite some time the java program did create the file. Then I ran into another problem, that it was not overwriting the log file. So i used file.delete() function after every time this log file got created via java.

Now, Java is not even creating the log file for some reason. If I run the above manually in command prompt, it runs absolutely fine, but not via java code. I can see this command getting run in the java log, but it does not create the log file even when i have removed the file.delete() function

I researched a lot on it but could not find any solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

its a long code..so i will tell you the relevant part.

I am calling a function from a thread. Code is below for that function:

```
public static void SaveACopyfileToServer(int auditid,String filepath,String fname,String tb_name,String plpgsql_path) throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();

        String plpgsql = "\""+plpgsql_path+"\" -U "+env.get("PG_USER")+" -w -h "+env.get("PG_HOST")+" -d "+env.get("PG_DB")+" -a -f "+"\""+filepath+"copy_"+tb_name+auditid+".sql\" 2> \"C:\\ER\\ETL\\logs\\psql.log\"";
        System.out.println(plpgsql);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(plpgsql);
        p.getOutputStream().close(); 
        p.waitFor();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        Calendar cal10 = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Data loaded for "+tb_name+auditid+" at "+sdf.format(cal10.getTime()));
    }
```

I have tried the following codes also:

```
String plpgsql = "\""+plpgsql_path+"\" -U "+env.get("PG_USER")+" -w -h "+env.get("PG_HOST")+" -d "+env.get("PG_DB")+" -a -f "+"\""+filepath+"copy_"+tb_name+auditid+".sql\" 2> \"C:\\ER\\ETL\\psql_" +auditid +".log\"";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe",plpgsql);
System.out.println(plpgsql);
Process p =pb.start();
p.getOutputStream().close();
p.waitFor();
```

and

```
String filename = filepath+"copy_"+tb_name+auditid+".sql";
String psqllog_file = "C:\\ER\\ETL\\logs\\psql_" +auditid +".log"; 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String [] { plpgsql_path, 
                              "-U", 
                              env.get("PG_USER"), 
                              "-w", 
                              "-h", 
                              env.get("PG_HOST"), 
                              "-d", 
                              env.get("PG_DB"), 
                              "-a", 
                              "-f", 
                              filename, 
                              "2>", 
                              psqllog_file });
```

If i run it through a batch file, then I am getting and error that Windows cannot find -U using the below code in java

```
String plpgsql = "\""+plpgsql_path+"\" -U "+env.get("PG_USER")+" -w -h "+env.get("PG_HOST")+" -d "+env.get("PG_DB")+" -a -f "+"\""+filepath+"copy_"+tb_name+auditid+".sql\" 2> \"C:\\ER\\ETL\\psql_" +auditid +".log\"";
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe","/c","start",plpgsql);
    System.out.println(plpgsql);
    Process p =pb.start();
    p.getOutputStream().close();
    p.waitFor();
```

I am stuck on this for a good amount of time now. Any help would be really really appreciated.

P.S: I am absolutely new to Stackoverflow, still trying to learn how to reply to comments to notify the other person, cz i think my replies are not being sent to the mailbox of others.

Comment: Might be worth looking at http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: @BrianAgnew in the early stages, it was creating the required log file, then i had put in a file.delete(), but then i removed it again...since that the code is not creating the log file.....there is no other jar file running...i have shut down my system also many a times.....

Comment: Could you output the content of `plpgsql` variable to the console and copy it here?

Comment: @StephaneM: Example of the variable plpgsql `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -w -h localhost -d erDev -a -f "C:\ER\ETL\copy_s_m_asset_459.sql" 2> "C:\ER\ETL\psql_459.log"`